# Как сделать, чтоб телеграм бот (Python) выводил значение переменной?

Tags: python, telegram, бот

Вот моя проблема.

```
     import telebot;
     from telebot import TeleBot

    bot: TeleBot = telebot.TeleBot("<TOKEN>");
    error=0
    @bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
   def start_command(message):
   bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "\n      Игра Частный Детектив.  \n     Убийство в день .\n "
                                "Пролог.\n \n  Служба спасения:   Служба спасения 911, чем я  могу вам помочь?\n \n "
                                "Садовник:   Да, здравствуйте. Мы нашли тело в поместье Роквалли. \n \n"
                                "Служба спасения:   По какому адресу?\n \n"
                                "Садовник:   Это здесь, в поместье Роквалли.\n \n"
                                "Служба спасения:   Особняк Роквалли?\n \n"
                                "Садовник:   Да, да. Я нашёл тело в кустах, в роще.\n \n"
                                "Служба спасения:   Вы проверили признаки жизни?\n \n"
                                "Садовник:   Уверяю вас, это уже не нужно, парень точно мёртв.\n \n"
                                "Служба спасения:   Вы знаете жертву?\n \n"
                                "Садовник:   Я не знаю, это белый мужчина. Он не из семьи Роквалли.\n С мистером и миссис Роквалли всё в порядке, и с их детьми тоже.\n \n"
                                "Служба спасения:  С кем я сейчас говорю?\n \n"
                                "Садовник:   Меня зовут Уильям Грегз, я садовник и сторож в поместье.\n \n"
                                "Служба спасения:   Хорошо. Полиция уже едет к вам.\n \n"
                                "Садовник:    Спасибо.\n \n" )
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"И так, Вы прибыли на место преступления. \n"
                               "Самое время начать опрос свидетелей и поиск улик.")
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"Информация.\n"""
                               "Лицо жертвы было изуродовано.\n Правая рука была отделена от"
                               "ТЕЛА.\n\n"  
                           "Считаете данную информацию полезной?")

  @bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])

    def get_answer(message, error=0):
        if message.text=='да':
     error = 0;
   elif message.text=='нет':
    error = error + 1;

      bot.polling()
```

Как вывести значение переменной error?

Comment: Разъехались отступы, подправьте код

Comment: Какой-то код видно, никакой проблем не видно